# Need a fast way to count and sum an iterable in a single pass

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can any one help me? I'm trying to come up with a way to compute

```
>>> sum_widths = sum(col.width for col in cols if not col.hide)
```

and also count the number of items in this sum, without having to make two passes over `cols`.

It seems unbelievable but after scanning the std-lib (built-in functions, itertools, functools, etc), I couldn't even find a function which would count the number of members in an iterable.  I found the function `itertools.count`, which sounds like what I want, but It's really just a deceptively named `range` function.

After a little thought I came up with the following (which is so simple that the lack of a library function may be excusable, except for its obtuseness):

```
>>> visable_col_count = sum(col is col for col in cols if not col.hide)
```

However, using these two functions requires two passes of the iterable, which just rubs me the wrong way.

As an alternative, the following function does what I want:

```
>>> def count_and_sum(iter):
>>>     count = sum = 0
>>>     for item in iter:
>>>         count += 1
>>>         sum += item
>>>     return count, sum
```

The problem with this is that it takes 100 times as long (according to `timeit`) as the sum of a generator expression form.

If anybody can come up with a simple one-liner which does what I want, please let me know (using Python 3.3).

**Edit 1**

Lots of great ideas here, guys. Thanks to all who replied. It will take me a while to digest all these answers, but I will and I will try to pick one to check.

**Edit 2**

I repeated the timings on my two humble suggestions (`count_and_sum` function and 2 separate `sum` functions) and discovered that my original timing was way off, probably due to an auto-scheduled backup process running in the background.

I also timed most of the excellent suggestions given as answers here, all with the same model. Analysing these answers has been quite an education for me: new uses for `deque`, `enumerate` and `reduce` and first time for `count` and `accumulate`. Thanks to all!

Here are the results (from my slow netbook) using the software I'm developing for display:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                 Count and Sum Timing                  │
├──────────────────────────┬───────────┬────────────────┤
│          Method          │Time (usec)│Time (% of base)│
├──────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│count_and_sum (base)      │        7.2│            100%│
│Two sums                  │        7.5│            104%│
│deque enumerate accumulate│        7.3│            101%│
│max enumerate accumulate  │        7.3│            101%│
│reduce                    │        7.4│            103%│
│count sum                 │        7.3│            101%│
└──────────────────────────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```

(I didn't time the complex and fold methods as being just too obscure, but thanks anyway.)

Since there's very little difference in timing among all these methods I decided to use the `count_and_sum` function (with an explicit `for` loop) as being the most readable, explicit and simple (Python Zen) and it also happens to be the fastest!

I wish I could accept one of these amazing answers as correct but they are all equally good though more or less obscure, so I'm just up-voting everybody and accepting my own answer as correct (`count_and_sum` function) since that's what I'm using.

What was that about "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."?

Comment: You realise that, if your timing information is accurate, the two-pass "rubs you the wrong way" solution is 50 times faster than your alternative? Sometimes it's better to be pragmatic :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo There are situations in which you don't want to iterate twice, such as when the generator is costly.

Comment: @Timothy, I agree whole-heatedly in general but this obviously isn't one of those cases, given the timings provided. I don't like doing things twice either but, if the alternative is doing it once and slower (with no other benefits), I'll choose pragmatism over dogmatism :-)

Comment: The function should not take 100 times as long! Something strange is going on there.

Comment: i may be missing something embarrassingly obvious. but why not `sum(iter), len(iter)` ?

Comment: Your first two samples have an extra condition `if not col.hide`, but that is missing in the `count_and_sum`. Why so?

Comment: @thefourtheye: I was intending ``count_and_sum`` to be a more general function and call it as: ``count, sum = count_and_sum(col.width for col in cols if not col.hide)`` but now that I've written it out I see the error of my plan. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DonO'Donnell Exactly. That program is missing an important piece of information. Please fix it. And DSM's `accumulate` looks good.

Comment: Could you post a little about how you arrived at the 100x slowdown figure? The precise command/code you used would be ideal. 100x slowdown doesn't smell right for that code.

Comment: Slapping `@numba.autojit` on `count_and_sum` makes it as fast as the deque method. Adding inn some logic for the conditional filtering and adding numba in the mix, might be quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the great answers, but I decided to use my original `count_and_sum` function, called as follows:

```
>>> cc, cs = count_and_sum(c.width for c in cols if not c.hide)
```

As explained in the edits to my original question this turned out to be the fastest and most readable solution.

Answer (score 109):

Using complex numbers

```
z = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
y = sum(x + 1j for x in z)
sum_z, count_z = y.real, int(y.imag)
print sum_z, count_z
18.0 5
```

Comment: If it wasn't for float numbers this would be a nice hack

Comment: @JBernardo, not sure i understand. I tried it with float numbers in the list and it calculated the correct sum

Comment: It's certainly clever but, as per Matt, I'm not sure if I mean that in a good way or in a "you're frackin' crazy" way :-)

Comment: Ah, but what if the sequence contains complex numbers :P +1 for making me laugh

Comment: @1_CR Yes, it does calculate correctly (until some value that does not fit into float or, like gnibbler said, a complex number)

Comment: Use complex numbers for **everything**.

Comment: I've added an answer that does the same thing but with numpy arrays, I think that's slightly cleaner but the idea is stolen from this.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich cleaner, but an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt `j` is the suffix for irrational numbers. When you compute the sum of some real numbers and add `1j` for each element, you are incremeting the irrational part of the complex number; therefore, you are using the irraitonal part as a counter while the real part holds the sum of the real numbers.

Comment: @Morwenn *Imaginary*, not *irrational*.

Comment: I think next time i will post the solution with `Trignometry`

Comment: I can bet that this dude has just studied `Complex Numbers` in his `Math` class :)

Comment: This is...amazing. It could use a proper explanation, simply with the idea that comments are supposed to be disposable. If all these comments were tossed out I'd have absolutely no idea what on earth this code was doing.

Comment: Can be optimised to `sum(map(1j.__add__(z))`.

Comment: I didn't understand this. My math is probably a little rusty. Care to explain a bit?

Comment: @nikhil, please refer Morwenn's explanation in the comments. He has expressed about 10 times better than  i ever could ;-)

Answer (score 49):

I don't know about speed, but this is kind of pretty:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> it = range(10)
>>> max(enumerate(accumulate(it), 1))
(10, 45)
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: given that the above executed in Python 3.3.1, I'm pretty sure you're wrong. :^)

Comment: @DSM Sorry :) It is available from [3.2](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) itself. +1

Comment: @DSM One more thing. If you look at the first two examples in the question, there is one extra condition `if not col.hide`, that is missing in the last example. `accumulate` may not be able to handle it.

Comment: @thefourtheye: I'm not sure I follow.  Why wouldn't that be entirely handled on the iterable side?  If I write `accumulate(col.width for col in cols if not col.hide)`, `accumulate` doesn't see, much less care, about what's going on inside.

Comment: @DSM Correct. Do you mind adding this to the answer?

Answer (score 29):

Adaption of DSM's answer. using `deque(... maxlen=1)` to save memory use.

```
import itertools 
from collections import deque 
deque(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(x), 1), maxlen=1)
```

timing code in ipython:

```
import itertools , random
from collections import deque 

def count_and_sum(iter):
     count = sum = 0
     for item in iter:
         count += 1
         sum += item
     return count, sum

X = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10**7)]
%timeit count_and_sum(X)
%timeit deque(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(X), 1), maxlen=1)
%timeit (max(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(X), 1)))
```

results: now faster than OP's method

```
1 loops, best of 3: 1.08 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 659 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop
```

Comment: Yeah i was a bit surprised myself on the relatively big difference. I just had a hunch that allocating memory for the list could be a bottleneck. For more complex generators, where the calculation of values take more time. The difference should be insignificant though.

Comment: But `max` doesn't allocate memory for the list.  At any instant only two tuples are stored, the one you're looking at and the last maximum.  I think it must be just that the deque implementation is very fast and/or the tuple comparison is slow.

Comment: @DSM ahh, well then all the unnecessary comparisons would be the problem. since we're only interested in the last element.

Comment: @DSM btw, wouldnt using `max` give the wrong value if the last element was negative? The second to last elements would then be larger then the last one

Comment: No, because the tuples that it's comparing -- the ones produced by `enumerate`, remember -- are always of the form `(i, value)` and `(i+1, next_value)`.  The values never come into play because it always decides which is greater based on the first element, the index.

Answer (score 23):

Here's some timing data that might be of interest:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import random, functools, itertools, collections

x = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10**5)]

def count_and_sum(it):
    c, s = 0, 0
    for i in it:
        c += 1
        s += i
    return c, s

def two_pass(it):
    return sum(i for i in it), sum(True for i in it)

def functional(it):
    return functools.reduce(lambda pair, x: (pair[0]+1, pair[1]+x), it, [0, 0])

def accumulator(it):
    return max(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(it), 1))

def complex(it):
    cpx = sum(x + 1j for x in it)
    return cpx.real, int(cpx.imag)

def dequed(it):
    return collections.deque(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(it), 1), maxlen=1)

'''

number = 100
for stmt in ['count_and_sum(x)',
             'two_pass(x)',
             'functional(x)',
             'accumulator(x)',
             'complex(x)',
             'dequed(x)']:
    print('{:.4}'.format(timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=setup, number=number)))
```

Result:

```
3.404 # OP's one-pass method
3.833 # OP's two-pass method
8.405 # Timothy Shields's fold method
3.892 # DSM's accumulate-based method
4.946 # 1_CR's complex-number method
2.002 # M4rtini's deque-based modification of DSM's method
```

Given these results, I'm not really sure how the OP is seeing a 100x slowdown with the one-pass method. Even if the data looks radically different from a list of random integers, that just shouldn't happen.

Also, M4rtini's solution looks like the clear winner.

---

To clarify, these results are in CPython 3.2.3. For a comparison to PyPy3, see [James_pic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21729046/1535629), which shows some serious gains from JIT compilation for some methods (also mentioned in [a comment by M4rtini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716589/need-a-fast-way-to-count-and-sum-an-iterable-in-a-single-pass/21716742#comment32859553_21716589).

Comment: Can you try with some larger value? So that creation of lambdas and initial assignments become insignificant.

Comment: @utdemir All the function definitions and variable assignments are in the setup, which doesn't count towards the time actually taken.

Comment: we create a list and a lambda in `functional` method, initialize two variables in `count_and_sum` method etc. But as your results suggest, they are too tiny to affect the result.

Comment: @utdemir Yes, but you have to spend time initialzing variables, creating lambdas, etc. if you actually want to use these functions. Not counting the time taken to do that would defeat the entire purpose of this exercise.

Comment: This is actually the only helpful answer. Instead of writing bogus code like many others, it shows how good the original code is.

Comment: @JBernardo: while I agree this answer is very helpful, I'm not sure what senshin would be comparing the OP's methods *against* if other people hadn't written answers.

Comment: @DSM But you don't see any timings on other answers and while some may yield pretty code, they do not fulfill the original problem

Comment: @senshin could you add my answer to the timings?

Comment: @JBernardo: the first sentences ask "Can any one help me? I'm trying to come up with a way to compute [stuff] without having to make two passes over cols."  The final sentence says "If anybody can come up with a simple one-liner which does what I want, please let me know (using Python 3.3)."  I think a fair reading of the OP's question is that one-pass, simplicity, and speed are all desiderata.

Comment: @senshin The 100x slowdown was mostly due to the ``count_and_sum`` being a function call, the ``sum(genexp)`` form was executed directly in the ``timeit`` param, which is how it would be done in my project's code. Your results, while informative, do not reflect the way in which the final code would be executed.

Comment: @DonO'Donnell Could you shed some light on the way the code will be executed? If it's possible to test code in a representative way, then we may be able to give you better info.

Answer (score 20):

As a follow-up to `senshin`'s answer, it's worth noting that the performance differences are largely due to quirks in CPython's implementation, that make some methods slower than others (for example, `for` loops are relatively slow in CPython). I thought it would be interesting to try the exact same test in PyPy (using PyPy3 2.1 beta), which has different performance characteristics. In PyPy the results are:

```
0.6227 # OP's one-pass method
0.8714 # OP's two-pass method
1.033 # Timothy Shields's fold method
6.354 # DSM's accumulate-based method
1.287 # 1_CR's complex-number method
3.857 # M4rtini's deque-based modification of DSM's method
```

In this case, the OP's one-pass method is fastest. This makes sense, as it's arguably the simplest (at least from a compiler's point of view) and PyPy can eliminate many of the overheads by inlining method calls, which CPython can't.

For comparison, CPython 3.3.2 on my machine give the following:

```
1.651 # OP's one-pass method
1.825 # OP's two-pass method
3.258 # Timothy Shields's fold method
1.684 # DSM's accumulate-based method
3.072 # 1_CR's complex-number method
1.191 # M4rtini's deque-based modification of DSM's method
```

Answer (score 5):

You can keep count inside the sum with tricks similar to this

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> cnt = count()
>>> sum((next(cnt), x)[1] for x in range(10) if x%2)
25
>>> next(cnt)
5
```

But it's probably going to be more readable to just use a for loop

Comment: This is practically the same as  Steinar Lima's answer, but with an overhead of creating tuples for side effects...

Comment: @JBernardo, it's just a different way of solving the count(0) problem

Comment: Well I don't think it was a problem, since you can simply do `cnt - 1` at the end... `next(cnt)*0 or x` should also work. Or even `~next(cnt) and x`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
from itertools import count

lst = range(10)
c = count(1)
tot = sum(next(c) and x for x in lst if x % 2)
n = next(c)-1
print(n, tot)

# 5 25
```

It's kind of a hack, but it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the Python syntax is off hand, but you could potentially use a fold.  Something like this:

```
(count, total) = fold((0, 0), lambda pair, x: (pair[0] + 1, pair[1] + x))
```

The idea is to use a seed of (0,0) and then at each step add 1 to the first component and the current number to the second component.

For comparison, you could implement `sum` as a fold as follows:

```
total = fold(0, lambda t, x: t + x)
```

Comment: That syntax would be `reduce(lambda pair, x: (pair[0]+1, pair[1]+x), a, (0,0))` after importing `functools.reduce`.

Comment: And this would be fast how?

Answer (score 3):

1_CR's complex number solution is cute but overly hacky. The reason it works is that a complex number is a 2-tuple, that sums elementwise. The same is true of numpy arrays and I think it's slightly cleaner to use those:

```
import numpy as np
z = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
y = sum(np.array([x, 1]) for x in z)
sum_z, count_z = y[0], y[1]
print sum_z, count_z
18 5
```

Comment: off all the different ways you could use numpy for this, this gotta be the absolutely worst performing one of them out there. just create an array of z. sum it and check it's size.

Comment: You're probably right. I rejected that because storing all the results might use too much memory, but now that I think about it, that's really quite unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Something else to consider: If it is possible to determine a *minimum* possible count, we can let the efficient built-in `sum` do part of the work:

```
from itertools import islice

def count_and_sum(iterable):
    # insert favorite implementation here

def count_and_sum_with_min_count(iterable, min_count):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    slice_sum = sum(islice(iterator, None, min_count))
    rest_count, rest_sum = count_and_sum(iterator)
    return min_count + rest_count, slice_sum + rest_sum
```

For example, using the `deque` method with a sequence of 10000000 items and `min_count` of 5000000, timing results are:

```
count_and_sum: 1.03
count_and_sum_with_min_count: 0.63
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?
It seems to work.

```
from functools import reduce

class Column:
    def __init__(self, width, hide):
        self.width = width
        self.hide = hide

lst = [Column(10, False), Column(100, False), Column(1000, True), Column(10000, False)]

print(reduce(lambda acc, col: Column(col.width + acc.width, False) if not col.hide else acc, lst, Column(0, False)).width)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might only need the sum & count today, but who knows what you'll need tomorrow!

Here's an easily extensible solution:

```
def fold_parallel(itr, **fs):
    res = {
        k: zero for k, (zero, f) in fs.items()
    }

    for x in itr:
        for k, (_, f) in fs.items():
            res[k] = f(res[k], x)

    return res

from operator import add

print(fold_parallel([1, 2, 3],
    count = (0, lambda a, b: a + 1),
    sum = (0, add),
))
# {'count': 3, 'sum': 6}
```