# Get percentage of a list that meets criteria

Tags: python, list

This is, of course, a very easy thing to do with loops and other ugly, non-pythonic things. Essentially, is there a method (preferably a one-liner), that will iterate through a list and get a percentage that holds a property? For instance,

```
def predicate(x):
    #Returns if x is even
    return x % 2 == 0

#Performed on [1,2,3,4]
50

#Performed on [5,3,7,2]
25
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: property shadows the build in `property` function and should be renamed

Comment: Where is your ugly, non-pythonic attempt?

Comment: Watch out for answers that can't handle empty, length 0, lists...

Comment: for loops are neither ugly nor unpythonic.  Where did people get the wrong-headed idea that huge one-liners are better than simple loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
100 * ( len([x for x in l if property(x)]) / len(l) )
```

Comment: This looks like it is probably faster than the other answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @theage: no, because it has to produce a list object, this one is slower. Test it with `timeit`.

Comment: In Python 2, this will also use integer division, which *will* lead to incorrect rounding. The 1 out of 4 second test case will be reported as *0%*, for example.

Comment: Last but not least, you want to test for `len(l)` **not** `len(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

Count what matches with `sum()`, then divide by the length, multiply by 100

```
def percentage(L, predicate):
    return (sum(1.0 for v in L if predicate(v)) / len(L)) * 100
```

No extra list object is created to produce the value, resulting in a constant memory algorithm.

Demo:

```
>>> def percentage(L, predicate):
...     return (sum(1.0 for v in L if predicate(v)) / len(L)) * 100
... 
>>> def property(x):
...     #Returns if x is even
...     return x % 2 == 0
... 
>>> percentage([1,2,3,4], property)
50.0
>>> percentage([5,3,7,2], property)
25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

And another alternative that takes advantage of `True` being `1` and `False` being `0`:

```
sum(map(property, your_list), 0.0) / len(your_list) * 100
```

Comment: Out of interest, why give the second argument to `sum()` here?

Comment: @NPE starting summing from a float, means it ends up with a float and doesn't end up with duff results for the division in Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> len(filter(property, l)) * 100 / len(l)
50
>>> l = [5, 3, 7, 2]
>>> len(filter(property, l)) * 100 / len(l)
25
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a result from [Need a fast way to count and sum an iterable in a single pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716589/need-a-fast-way-to-count-and-sum-an-iterable-in-a-single-pass/21717164#21717164)

We get a answer capable of taking any iterable, including any generator expression. Since you can't normally take the length of a generator this could be useful.

```
def predicate(x):
    #Returns if x is even
    return x % 2 == 0


def percentage(iterable, conditional):
    import itertools 
    from collections import deque 
    it = (1.0 if conditional(i) else 0.0 for i in iterable)
    res = deque(enumerate(itertools.accumulate(it), 1), maxlen=1)
    if len(res) == 0:
        return 0.0
    return 100.0 * res[0][1]/res[0][0]

L1 = [1,2,3,4] 
percentage(L1, predicate)
# 50.0
L2 = [5,3,7,2]
percentage(L2, predicate)
```

Comment: This is overkill for regular lists though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that's super fast, works in Python 2 & 3, handles empty lists, and is a one-liner:

```
def predicate(x):
    return x % 2 == 0  # x even?

for lst in [1,2,3,4], [5,3,7,2], []:
    print(0.0 if not lst else sum(map(predicate, lst), 0.0) / len(lst) * 100)
```

Output:

```
50.0
25.0
0.0
```