# how to modify average function in python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

How do I change the code below so that when a minus number is found it skips it (e.g `-1`) and returns the averages of only positive numbers? (e.g `0` and above)

```
def Avg(B):
    sum = 0
    for b in B:
        sum = sum + b
    return sum/len(B)
```

Comment: if b < 0: skip it. Just add the validation;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if b in B is negative, if it is skip it. In the end you need to remember how many numbers you skipped to calculate a correct average. I used the integer variable called negatives.

```
def Avg(B):
    sum = 0
    negatives = 0
    for b in B:
        if b >= 0:
            sum = sum + b
        else:
            negatives += 1
    return sum/(len(B)-negatives)
```

Alternatively you can count the positives (it avoids the superfluous call to len and more directly expresses 'average' - the sum of the things being averaged by their number. Thanks [@pvg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087125/pvg)):

```
def Avg(B):
    sum = 0
    positives = 0
    for b in B:
        if b >= 0:
            sum = sum + b
            positives += 1
    return sum/positives
```

Anyway you should probably use another name for sum so you won't shadow `sum` function of the standart library.

Comment: Please add some description about the changes you have made!

Comment: You're better off just counting the positives. it's more direct and clearer.

Comment: @kiner_shah I was about to do it

Comment: It's not the same - it avoids the superfluous call to len and more directly expresses 'average' - the sum of the things being averaged by their number.

Comment: @pvg Yes you are right. I wasn't thinking about optimization

Comment: it's really more about clarity. an average is a sum of the elements divided by their number. it's clearer when the computation looks like the definition of an average and `sum/(len(B)-negatives)` looks a lot less like it.

Comment: @pvg Yes you are right. Thank you. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks Luca this was awesome

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't use `sum` as a name, it will mask the built in `sum` function.

Secondly if you require only positives, filter your initial list `B` in a list comprehension and then iterate through it:

```
def Avg(B):
    mysum = 0
    pos = [i for i in B if i>0]
    for i in pos:
        mysum += i
    return mysum/len(pos)
```

Using the built-in `sum`, you can, of course, shorten this to:

```
def Avg(B):
    pos = [i for i in B if i>0]
    return sum(pos)/len(pos)
```

Comment: This creates an extra list for no particular reason and traverses the data nearly twice.

Comment: @pvg Yes, it does. I believe it is cleaner than also keeping a counter around in order to divide by the number of elements summed.

Comment: @pvg Nope, the second approach is faster (the first is only offered for OPs convenience) since the list-comp is optimized for quick creation of lists and `sum` gets things done in `C` speed. The downside is the additional list creation, which I agree on.

Comment: you're still traversing the data twice. But more importantly, the person asking obviously hasn't developed a good grasp of conditionals yet and you're giving them list comprehensions. It's utter overkill and code golfing at the expense of clarity.

Comment: @pvg what exactly is unclear about it? Even relatively new to the language it still reads as English and the return statement makes it quite obvious...

Comment: Answers aren't solely for the OP @pvg and list-comps with `sum` being called code-golfing is, to the say the least, an exaggerated opinion. Either way, thanks for your comments and the constructive feed-back :-)

Comment: If you really want to see some OTT solutions - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716589/need-a-fast-way-to-count-and-sum-an-iterable-in-a-single-pass :p

Comment: @JonClements The point isn't that this is bad python or obfuscated code in general.

Comment: Jim this was useful too

Answer (score 0):

```
def Avg(B):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for b in B:
        if b < 0:
            continue
        sum += b
        count += 1
    return sum/count
```